Ошибка при import виджета KivyMD
Помогите в такой проблеме. Пытаюсь использовать пример создания окна Dialog в KivyMD который указан в документации версии: 2.0.1, однако получаю ошибку на данный виджет и на другие. В шапке прописано как положено:
from kivymd.uix.dialog.dialog import MDDialogIcon

Пробую создать переменную:
button_1 = MDDialogIcon(icon="refresh")

На что получаю ошибку: cannot import name 'MDDialogIcon' from 'kivymd.uix.dialog.dialog'
Версия Kivy - 2.3.0, kivymd - 1.2.0, Python - 3.11.9

Подскажите, как исправить?
